# Django update form: does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: jquery, django, date, datepicker, frontend

I am using Django in the backend to save a date that the user inputs. Then later, I want to allow the user to update that date input by bringing them to a new page, showing them the old date input, and allowing them to update it.

I am using a datepicker input field for the frontend to easily allow the user to pick a date.

After I input my date, and I go to the update page to change it, the datepicker input field on the update page is empty every time.

In the console I see

`The specified value "Jul. 4, 1776" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".`

I think the problem is that when I am retrieving the date from the database it is coming in as a different format than the forntend wants it. The date is coming from the backend as Jul. 4, 1776 format and the frontend form needs it in 1776-07-04.

I was wondering how I can fix this so both frontend and backend are happy, and the old date inputted by the user is shown in the update page datepicker input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this in **settings.py** seemed to fix the issue

```py
DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'
```

Answer (score 2):

DATE_FORMAT in settings.py did not solved the problem for me

Date are stored in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format in the database and in order to avoid this Javascript error message I had to specify the same format in the form definition `format='%Y-%m-%d'`. The `forms.SelectDateWidget()` works fine but I didn't want to use it.

```py
    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ['id', 'title', 'summary_img', 'summary_txt', 'msg_nextdate']
            widgets = {
                'summary_txt': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':6}),
                'msg_nextdate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}, format='%Y-%m-%d'),
                # 'msg_nextdate': forms.SelectDateWidget()
                }
```

If `USE_I18N = True` is set in settings.py, **date display** on web navigator depends on computer regional settings.

- mm/dd/yyyy for US/UK format
- dd/mm/yyyy for FR/BE format

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

adding this to your settings.py:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

OR

```
{{my_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}
```

Comment: When I put {{ form.date_field|date:"Y-m-d" }} the form just disappears from the frontend without any errors on the frontend or the backend. When I remove the date template filter the forms comes back again. Does the template filter apply to only values or datepicker forms as well?

Comment: Try using the first option.